# PHP Erro " mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given", ao enviar informações de várias input

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo uma página com cadastro de valores de produtos, gostaria de saber como faço um `Insert Into` dos valores de um *while*?

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Item</th>
   <th>Código</th>
   <th>Produto</th>
   <th>Valor</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
<?php while($dado_produto = $result_produtos->fetch_array()){ ?>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><?php echo $dado_produto['cod']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $dado_produto['descricao']; ?></td>
  <td><input type = "text" name="valor[<?php echo $dado_produto['cod']; ?>]"/></td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?> 
 </tbody>
</table>
</div> 
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

O arquivo que recebe os **valor.php**

Eu pesquisei usei um código que achei na internet para, mas não estou conseguindo, esta dando erro.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include_once("../../controle/conexao.php");
// Início da consulta
$sql = "INSERT INTO `produtos` (`cod`, `valor`) VALUES";

// Para cada elemento produto:
foreach($_POST['valor'] as $cod=>$val){
$produto = $cod['codigo'];
$valor = $val['valores'];

// Monta a parte consulta de cada produto
$sql .= " (NULL, '{$produto}', '{$valor}'),";}

// Tira o último caractere (vírgula extra)
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);

// Executa a consulta
mysqli_query($sql);
$cadastrados = mysqli_affected_rows();
?>
```

Aparece o erro:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in E:\home\valor.php on line 10

A linha 10 é a :

```
$sql .= " (NULL, '{$produto', '{$valor}'),";}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Tá sobrando uma virgula não tá e faltando um } ? $sql .= " (NULL, '{$produto}', '{$valor}')";}

Comment: Coloquei o } logo apos produto e removi a virgula, mas ainda apresenta o mesmo erro, voltei a virgula e apresenta também o mesmo erro.

Comment: Parece que faltou ponto e vírgula em: `$valor = $val['valores']`

Comment: coloquei, e agora aparece o erro PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in E:\home\valor.php on line 11
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in E:\home\valor.php on line 12

Comment: O campo onde está a colocar NULL não estará definido como "not null"? Experimente colocar  "1" em vez de NULL

Comment: Quando vc usa as funções `mysqli` o primero argumento quase sempre é a conexão, o segundo a consulta no caso do `myqli_query()`. Veja como está `mysqli_query($sql);`

Comment: @rray realmente os erros que o André Baill e mais o que você apontou, era uns dos problemas, deletei  $produto = $cod['codigo'];
$valor = $val['valores']; agora está funcionando corretamente. Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Se você estiver usando PDO.

A melhor coisa a se fazer é preparar o seu SQL, até para garantir alguns projeto de SQL Injection.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO produtos VALUES (:cod,:valor)'

$sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt = $sth->execute(array(':cod' => 150, ':valor' => 10));
```

Comment: não estou usando PDO

Comment: O que está usando? Mysqli? Algo assim? $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

Comment: Correto mysqli.

Comment: Postei outra resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando mysqli, ficaria assim.

```
<?php
// Criando a conexão
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);

// Verificando a conexão
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Falhou a Conexão: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// preparando o bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO (tabela) (nome, sobrenome, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
//sss são variáveis tipo String. Consulte aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $nome, $sobrenome, $email);

//executando
$stmt->execute();

//Você pode executar várias vezes, em um for, por exemplo.

$firstname = "Maria";
$lastname = "Da Silna";
$email = "maria@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

$firstname = "Julia";
$lastname = "dos Santos";
$email = "julia@example.com";
$stmt->execute();


$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Não entendi nada

Comment: Agora formatei a resposta.